# Taskqueue run only 1 task from the queue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

Im using google appengine taskqueue to run one of my api in the background. this api takes about 3 seconds to run, but I add it to the queue several time like that:

```
while  len(lst) > 0:
        logging.info("calling my_api")
        taskqueue.add(url='/my_api', params={ 'param_a': lst.pop(0) },
                      retry_options= TaskRetryOptions(task_retry_limit=1) )
```

when len(lst) is 2 the taskqueue perform only one call to '/my_api'(I see in the log 2 entries of "calling my_api"). im using the most basic backend (B1). any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: Check the logs for /my_api and see if one of them caused an error.

Comment: no, In the log I see there /my_app was called only one time and finished successfuly.

Comment: Does your calling app have an exception/error?

Comment: no exceptions at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop setting such a low `task_retry_limit`. Also, make sure that in your app.yaml you have `threadsafe: true` so your tasks can run concurrently without needing additional instances to be started.

Comment: thanks for your comment. currently I have "threadsafe: false" so it might be it, ill try and update.